# Why POST method return 500 error for array of values with successfully inserted value?

Tags: swagger, loopbackjs, openapi, loopback4

In loopback 4 There is a strange issue when I POST a single value like :

```
{
email: "sit@leoVivamusnibh.net",
password: "430975896"
}
```

in swagger, there is no issue report but when I post an array of values like:

```
[{
email: "metus.facilisis.lorem@sitamet.org",
password: "168978823"
},
{
email: "fringilla@enim.org",
password: "933013104"
}]
```

the value was posted to the database but this error appears:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
  }
}
```

and in console shows the following lines:

> Unhandled error in POST /users: 500 TypeError: model.toObject is not a
>   function
>       at UserRepository.toEntity (D:\apps\test\node_modules@loopback\repository\src\repositories\legacy-juggler-bridge.ts:471:39)
>       at UserRepository.create (D:\apps\test\node_modules@loopback\repository\src\repositories\legacy-juggler-bridge.ts:338:17)

**user model**

```
@model({ settings: {} })
export class User extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true
  })
  id: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string'
  })
  email: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string'
  })
  password: string;
  constructor(data?: Partial<User>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

**user controller**:

```
async create(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(User),
        },
      },
    })
    user: Omit<User, 'id'>,
  ): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository.create(user,
                                    //{ exclude: ['id'] }
                                      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in LoopBack 4, the `POST` method does not accept an array of model instances to create, it works for a single model only.

Having said that, LoopBack should not respond with a 500 error when the request contains an array of objects. I would expect a `422 Unprocessable Entity` response instead.

Can you fill a bug please? https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/new/choose

Comment: I already did it please check the report.[error 500 when using an array in post method.](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3700)

Answer (score 1):

The array you are requesting in the request body is fine as you mentioned.

The thing is if you want to create these users profile in the database 
You will have to do something like:

```
async create(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(User),
        },
      },
    })
    userList: User[],
  ): Promise<User> {
      return await Promise.all(
        userList.forEach(user => {
          return await this.userRepository.create(user);
       ))
  }
```

Hopefully, this helps, write to me if you have any query or suggestion.
Thank you